# What is the difference between executeNonQuery() and executeUpdate() in java?

Tags: java, sql

I had read about `executeNonQuery()` and `executeUpdate()` methods in java. But could not understand any difference among them.
It says return type of  `executeUpdate()` is an int that indicates the `number of rows` affected, or `0` if using a `DDL statement`, and is used to Runs the given SQL statement, which can be an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE statement`; or an `SQL statement` that returns nothing, such as an `SQL DD`L statement.

same is what I read about `executeNonQuery()` method.

So what is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: If you're talking about the methods of the [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) interface, I don't see an executeNonQuery anywhere. Are you sure that's the name you're thinking about?

Comment: Please, provide a link, where did you get info about `executeNonQuery()` method.

Comment: also state which API u are using , means class with complete package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two methods are entirely equivalent, the only meaningful difference being that `executeUpdate()` is part of the Java `java.sql.Statement` interface, while `executeNonQuery()` is a .NET method in the `SqlCommand` class! As you might imagine, many people would consider this little detail to be of some importance.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know ,`ExecuteNonQuery()` is there in **.NET** to execute `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` queries. As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) :

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

I have never heard of such method in JAVA API.

[executeQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378540.aspx) is used for command objects, like fire a "select statement" to database and fetch values.